# Default value is not stored in model

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    release_year = models.IntegerField()
    number_in_stock = models.IntegerField()
    daily_rate = models.FloatField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):


    return self.title
```

[Admin interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpW0p.png)

The above code is my models class and i have given a default value to the
ImageField .

After saving the data my image field is still empty.
Whats the prooblem ?

Comment: How does your database look like? As `null` or as an empty string?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this in your setting.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

Also, you will have to add the image in the static folder in your project for it work properly.

Comment: Yes I have added, but I have a doubt that static files are used for adding CSS and js files right ? And MEDIA_URL is used for images ?

Comment: Not necessarily, static files are used for css and js but also can be used for default images, media will be used in case the user has uploaded another image and he/she wants to use that, otherwise you store the default in static only

Comment: got it...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628236/12381259), the Media URL/Root and Static URL/Root collectively help Django process images for your application.

When you add the default image in `models.py`, make sure to put `'/static/image.jpg'` and once you're rending in the template load static with `{% load static %}`.

Comment: That means I have to add the default.jpg in the static folder ?

Comment: yup, that's where it'll be stored (locally)